# How to use prepared statement with with multiple union?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, union

I am trying to convert my mysqli union code into prepared statement. i convert all other code using prepared statement but i am not able to convert this search query.

PHP : this is my original code -

```
    $string3 = $_GET['search'];

    $search_exploded = explode (" ", $string3)

    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
        {
            $x++;
            if($x==1)
                $construct .="movie_name LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
            else
                $construct .="or movie_name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        }


    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each2)
        {
            $y++;
            if($y==1)
                $construct2 .="show_name LIKE '%$search_each2%' AND show_name not like '$filter2'";
            else
                $construct2 .="or show_name LIKE '%$search_each2%' AND show_name not like '$filter2'";
        }


    $construct4 .="movie_name1 LIKE '$string3%'";

    $getquery = mysqli_query($conn, "(SELECT '1' as sb, id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo where movie_name LIKE '$string3%')
                union
          (SELECT '2' as sb, id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo
                where ($construct4) AND NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo where movie_name LIKE '$string3%')) 
              union
          (SELECT '3' as sb, id,poster,show_name,show_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM tvshows where show_name LIKE '$string3%') 
                union
          (SELECT '4' as sb, id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo
                where ($construct) AND id NOT IN
          (SELECT id FROM movieinfo where movie_name LIKE '$string3%' or movie_name1 LIKE '$string3%'))
                union
          (SELECT '5' as sb, id,poster,show_name,show_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM tvshows where $construct2) order by sb,RAND($rand) LIMIT $start, $per_page")or die(mysqli_error());
```

i am trying to convert this into prepared statement. i tried this but its not working. i am not able bind multiple parameters in union.

PHP : this is what i am trying

```
    $string3 = $_GET['search'];

    $search_exploded = explode (" ", $string3)

    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
        {
            $x++;
            if($x==1)
                $construct .="movie_name LIKE ? ";
            else
                $construct .="or movie_name LIKE ? ";
        }

    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each2)
        {
            $y++;
            if($y==1)
                $construct2 .="show_name LIKE ? AND show_name not like ? ";
            else
                $construct2 .="or show_name LIKE ? AND show_name not like ? ";
        }

    $construct4 .="movie_name1 LIKE ? ";

    $getquery = "(SELECT '1' as sb, id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo where movie_name LIKE ? )
                union
          (SELECT '2' as sb, id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo
                where ($construct4) AND NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo where movie_name LIKE ? )) 
              union
          (SELECT '3' as sb, id,poster,show_name,show_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM tvshows where show_name LIKE ? ) 
                union
          (SELECT '4' as sb, id,poster,movie_name,movie_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM movieinfo
                where ($construct) AND id NOT IN
          (SELECT id FROM movieinfo where movie_name LIKE ? or movie_name1 LIKE ? ))
                union
          (SELECT '5' as sb, id,poster,show_name,show_name1,year,type,season,imdb FROM tvshows where $construct2) order by sb";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $getquery)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssss", $param_term1, $param_term1, $param_term1, $param_term1, $param_term1, $param_term1, $param_term1, $param_term1, $param_term3);
         $param_term1 =$string3;
         $param_term2 =$search_each;
         $param_term3 =$filter;

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                $foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($result);


     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

      }
      }
      }
      }
```

my original mysqli code working fine. please help me to convert this into prepared statement.

Comment: Are you getting errors? If so please show us the error(s)

Comment: You need to convert your paramters i.e. `$param_term1` to contain the wildcards where ever you want them so `$param_term1 = $param_term1 . '%'` before you use them in the bind

Comment: Can you give me one example?

Comment: I did in the comment above

Comment: @vinay This code looks "heavy-handed".  I'd like to try to refine it for better performance and provide this page with an acceptable solution.  Can you please offer a minimal SQLFiddle demo which clarifies your query logic and displays your desired result?  (Please be very careful to construct a demo with search values and sample rows that will express how the logic will affect the result.)